# Insert trigger: set value from procedure ends with 3609 error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have to check if a specific value of an insert is null. If it is null, I want to give it a value from a stored procedure. This procedure returns a number like a sequence, but because I have SQL Server 2008 I had to create it myself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Get_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_SEQUENCE ( @value BIGINT OUTPUT)
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT dbo.BAV_Personalarchiv_Sequence WITH (TABLOCKX) DEFAULT VALUES;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @value = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO
```

I want to use the created value in my Insert Trigger if 'SYSROWID' is null (if it is null, it should be the only record with it) :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NT_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_MITARBEITER_INSERT]  
   ON [dbo].[NT_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_MITARBEITER]  
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If (SELECT SYSROWID FROM INSERTED) IS NULL 
    Begin
        DECLARE @value BIGINT;
        EXECUTE dbo.Get_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_SEQUENCE @value OUTPUT;

        Update dbo.NT_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_MITARBEITER 
        SET SYSROWID = @value
        where SYSROWID IS NULL
    End
END
```

But sadly it returns with an 3609 error and rolls back the transaction.

Testing only the Execute and Update works without a problem:

```
DECLARE @value BIGINT;
EXECUTE dbo.Get_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_SEQUENCE @value OUTPUT;
Update dbo.NT_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_MITARBEITER 
SET SYSROWID = @value
where SYSROWID IS NULL
```

What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that the rollback in the procedure causes the trigger to end with the error. My workaround is to delete the values of the "sequence"-table before I create a new value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Get_BAV_PERSONALARCHIV_SEQUENCE ( @value BIGINT OUTPUT)
AS
    delete from dbo.BAV_Personalarchiv_Sequence
    INSERT dbo.BAV_Personalarchiv_Sequence WITH (TABLOCKX) DEFAULT VALUES;

    SELECT @value = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO
```